# How to set HttpServletResponse on Jboss EAP 6.2?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss

I have a simple method where I need to change the contentType to "text/plain" but when I am using Jboss EAP 6.2 it is ignored and the returned value is "application/json.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public class UploadController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Result foo(MultipartFile arquivo, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        return uploadService.saveFile(arquivo);
    }
}
```

I am using SpringMVC (rest controller) and Jackson to parse to JSON. The exactly same method works fine when I use Jetty instead of Jboss.

I can't use @RequestMapping(produces="text/plain") because the actual method has a bit more logic into it and sometimes it will return application/json others text/plain, depending if the request came from IE9 browser or not.

Can someone please tell me how can I set the contentType on Jboss?

Comment: I don't like the sound of a service that might return a random content type.

Comment: I actually got confused by your answer. How can the frontend ajax request determine the response type?

Comment: I edited the original quest to explain why it returns different content types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way I could get this working for Jboss was creating a different method for IE9:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ie9", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public String fooIE9(@RequestParam("arquivo") MultipartFile arquivo) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer();
    return ow.writeValueAsString(uploadService.saveFile(arquivo));
}
```